# why is curl_exec() returning string(1) " ", when the url returns a json on postman

Tags: php, json, curl

I am using `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);` and try to listen to an url.
The Url seems to be working fine (at least on postmen I get a full json).

*The Problem:* I do not get the json string I am hoping for with `curl_exec` but instead I get a string with a single space in it.

Normally I would assume there is a problem with my curl but since a string(0) meens false and mine is a string(1) I must have done something right.

Sadly I just cant seem to find anything on the net on why it isn´t giving me the full site as string.

Where should I start looking for the problem?

my code for Curl:

```
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Send the request & save response to $resp
    $resp = curl_exec($curl);
    var_dump($resp);
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: _"since a string(0) meens false"_ - No, a string(0) just means an empty string (which can still be a valid response if the server doesn't return anything). An empty string in PHP is considered a "falsy" value, but that's not the same thing. It's hard to know what the issue is without knowing what the server expects. It could be that you're required to send a user agent and that postman adds that automatically (just a guess and an example). In postman, you can see the cURL equivalent of the request it makes, so check if it passes more info than what you're doing.

Comment: thank you for the answer. sadly i don't quite understand what you meen by: "In postman, you can see the cURL equivalent of the request it makes, so check if it passes more info than what you're doing". Could you explain how i can proceed to look for the mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It code looks fine and you must get json response.
now can you just verify below things.

1. Just hit the URL directly on browser to check it returning any response or not (not take care if URL need any authentication)
2. Check if you have not used any CORS.
3. check is there any space before json response

Comment: Thank you for answering my question!
1. the url i am speaking of uses POST and so i can´t use it in a regular browser. Thats why i´m using postmen browser to check the url. 
2. I don't use any CORS to my knowledge.
3. The is no space before the returned json
Do you have any other idears on how to proceed?

Comment: as per your comment (#1), you are using POST request. if this URL accept POST request then you must include this option too:
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

Comment: thanks again! Sadly the response is still string(1) " ".
Can i provide any additional info that would help to identify the problem?

Comment: you please give me the $url value and hope you are not sending any post data on this url to get response. if sending post data, give that data too which was working in postman

Comment: while typing out the url to you i found out that i forgot a '/' in the very beginning.
While i am terrably sry for asking for help with such a dumb question, i am allthough very greatfull for your help!!! you saved my weekend!!!

Comment: Thanks to you too